# How to get the lat/lon coordinates along a road?

Tags: google-maps

I'd like to get the lat/lon coordinates of points along a road, say every 100 meters or so.  I could go to Google Maps and manually click on points, but I'd like to do this automatically.

Comment: Can't you use a GPS?

Comment: @Omne No, because then I'd have to drive along the entire road, which might not be anywhere close to where I live.  GPS measurements can also be off by tens of meters.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this (from Google maps, at least).